# How to load images in UICollectionView "without Scroll"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, lazy-loading, uicollectionviewcell

I am able to load Images in `UICollectionView`, using following code, but the problem is, It will load images after the screen is Scrolled. Without Scroll it will just display only Empty Cells.

Note:- I am not loading images from any link(API), It is from images.xcassets file or supporting Files.

Here is code for `UICollectionView`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController()
@end
@implementation ViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
collectionImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"car1.jpeg",@"car2.jpeg",@"car3.jpeg",@"car4.jpeg",@"car5.jpeg",@"car6.jpeg", nil];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return collectionImages.count;
}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier =@"Cell";
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView * collectionImageView = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:100];

    collectionImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[collectionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
return cell;
}

@end
```

Following Image, When I run program but without scrolling.If I scroll, it will load image one-by one.
 
[image]

Comment: try `cell.collectionImageView.image`

Comment: @Sanket are you using UICollectionViewCell class?

Comment: by default collection view load images for only visible cells

Comment: @aaisataev, 'cell.collectionImageView.image' is giving error. Can you explain it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

call

```
[collectionImageView reloadData]
```

at

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: It will go in infinite loop. Can you explain how to do that and how it will work?